How to notate repeat marks on non-classical tunes? The form is A B C D A B C D D E
I have a song with A B C D A B C D D E. Is it good enough, or is there any better alternative?


How about repeat sign?

Is it just this many measures???  Or is A standing in for a whole passage

Every marks stand for a whole passage.

Firstly, when there are two different segno marks in the score, the second one is usually written with the normal segno symbol doubled ($$) rather using a different symbol.*
Secondly, when there are instructions stacked vertically, I’d expect the upper instruction to apply first.  But to make this explicit you can use: Ia volta (prima volta, “1st time”), IIa volta (seconda volta, “2nd time”), etc.
Thirdly, when you are going back to the very start of the piece a D.S. (dal segno, “from the sign”) mark isn’t really the right repeat to use; there is a related type of repeat mark: D.C. (da capo, “from the head”) which means to go back to the start, and this doesn’t require a symbol.
Applying these changes we get:

Another type of notation you might want to use is repeat barlines.  When these are nested together with D.S./D.C. repeats, the barline repeat gets precedence for the first pass through, and gets ignored afterwards.†  So, the explicit seconda volta part of the instruction isn’t required. We arrive at this reasonable-looking form:

Perhaps though, the clearest option to read, as mentioned in Aaron’s answer, is to use a repeat barline and write out section D twice:


$ I’m using this as a character replacement for the segno symbol:

* If there are more than two segno points they are usually numbered like this: $3$, $4$, etc.
† If there are alternative endings, then only the last ending is played on the D.C./D.S. pass.

The version you've written is correct, but will be confusing to most musicians and will require explanation.
The best — by which I mean clearest — way is to write out the final D E explicitly.
A B C D :|| D E
If it's absolutely necessary to write using the least space possible, then the best option is to make the last measure of D three separate endings. The first ending is D.C., the second is D.S. (with the segno at D), and the third moving into E.


It depends on the structure of the piece, but there is a possibility to use a repeat sign or coda sign instead of 3rd volta. One possibility is to use a repeat sign instead of D.C. Another possibility is to use D.C. but use repetition sign instead of segno.

Won't a repeat sign overlap with segno?

@will Are you asking me or Vit Henych? If Vit, remember to @ him.

Anyone would be welcome to answer.

The answer would depend on the application.
Repeats were/are partly used to save on time for the copyist: today with computer music writing software this is not any important consideration anymore. Repeats also saves on paper when printed. Quite a few musicians uses iPad-s today so saving paper might be less of an issue.
In some musical contexts the reapeat indicates that the first time through should be played as written, and the second time should be embellished with thrills and ornaments, sometimes improvised.
In some musical contexts repeats creates more problems then they solve and it is better to write out the full music. One extreme example may be film music. Musicians generally sight-read without much of rehearsal. You might suddendly find that you need to remove or add a bar somewhere to fit edits done to the film. Here it is much better to be able to say, remove eg bar 78 (which happens to be the second time D is played).
As a musician, I generally preferr not to have repeats, DS or DC, but that is probably only a personal preference.
